# When using Appcenter, can I still call VersionTracking inside the App constructor?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The application I am working with uses AppCenter with code like this:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VersionTracking.Track();
        VersionChecks();
        VersionChecks();
        DB.CreateTables();
        DB.GetSettings();
        DB.PopulateTables();
        SetDeviceInfo();
        SetResourceColors();
        SetResourceDimensions();
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        AppCenter.Start("xx", typeof(Crashes), typeof(Push));
        Analytics.TrackEvent(VersionTracking.CurrentVersion);
    }
```

Although I don't see any error messages when it starts up I am concerned about the way this is coded as from what I can see the App constructor fires first followed by the OnStart().

So if this happens, how can VersionTracking work. Should that code not be in the OnStart and how about the additional code that I have which sets up the application?

Would appreciate any advice that people can offer about the use of AppCenter with Xamarin forms.

Comment: first, of course the constructor runs before OnStart.  The constructor always run first.  Second, what is your specific concern about VersionTracking?  That has no dependency on AppCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

Yes, you can use `Xamarin.Essentials.VersionTracking` in the constructor of `App`.

## Explanation

You are confusing three different SDKs: Xamarin.Essentials, Xamarin.Forms and AppCenter.

- `VersionTracking` is an API in [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin).
- `App` is a subclass of the [`Xamarin.Forms.Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application) API.
- `AppCenter.Start` is an API in the [`AppCenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin)

These are three independent SDKs and each can be used independently of the others.

Answer (score 0):

`Xamarin.Forms` app startup flow is like : `Native App` Startup -> `Xamarin.Forms.Application` Startup

Your App class is instantiated only after Native app has finished loading.

As versioning is managed by native app, there is no problem in initialising `VersionTracking` in constructor, as Native app has fully loaded by this time.